# Splash Screen with message in FireMonkey

Tags: firemonkey, splash-screen

I want a splash screen with a `tLabel` on it. This `tLabel` will be used to show the progress of the initialization tasks for the application, such as: "Starting up databases", "Setting up forms", etc.

I have tried the following code, in the project file:

```
  Application.Initialize;
  FormSplash := TFormSplash.Create( Application );
  FormSplash.OpenSplash;
  FormSplash.ShowProgress;
  Application.Run;
```

It shows the splash-screen properly. However, the `tLabel` that should show each text posted to it in sequence when the splash-screen appears, shows only the last text posted. This happens even if I put a `Sleep` command after each text posted. I tried to post the texts on the `FormCreate`, `FormShow` and `FormActivate` events with the same result.

The application is for Windows 32.

Comment: It will be easier to help if you can be more specific. "No success" is not very descriptive :-) What happens? Doesn't the form show at all or is it not updated with the text you want? and what platform are you on (Windows, Mac, IOS, Android)?

Comment: Have you considered Repainting, Refreshing or whatever the appropriate method for updating the controls at runtime is?

Comment: Yes. I tried that also. It seems that Windows waits until all the paintings are done, and after that, it shows the splash-screen. The way I expect things should happen is: 1-show the splash-screen, 2-show the first text posted, 3-wait for a second so it can be read, 4-repeat steps 2 and 3 until all the texts are posted. In the VCL environment, it worked fine.

Comment: Wait a minute. You expect your users to read the messages in the splash and even delay the program in order to display them? How long would it take to start the application without delays? If it is less than 5 seconds can the thing. I would even say 10s  are bearable.

Comment: Yes, I expect the users to read the messages, but the delay would take only a few seconds. Most applications that display splash-screens, have a text line on the bottom that shows the progress of the startup process. When the startup process has finished, then they show the main form. For some of them, the startup process is quite long. Take, for instance, RAD Studio itself. Likewise, Microsoft Office applications use the same approach and the startup process is moderately long. Besides, the question I asked is about how to make it possible, the time it takes is irrelevant.

Comment: Of course, you are right. Sorry about that. So how exactly are you updating the message label? Sleep will put your main thread to sleep, so that wont help much. Perhaps application.ProcessMessages will do the trick.

Comment: The main form is the splash-screen form. In turn, the splash-screen form has a `tlabel`, that shows the text messages that informs the user about the progress of the startup process. When each startup method begins, the text message is assigned to the `Text` property of the `tLabel`, and it should show up until the next startup method begins, when the next text message is assigned to the `Text` property of the `tLabel`, and so on, until the startup process is finished. At this moment, the splash-screen form is closed and freed. In sequence the application's main form is showed.

Comment: @Sherlock. Thanks a lot! Application.ProcessMessages did the trick! If suits you, post an answer so I can check it as right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Between changing the contents of your label you should allow the application to react to those changes. The simplest possibility is to use Application.ProcessMessages.